# Log user information after successful login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

In Identity core, I am trying to log the user information after successful login but I am just getting **empty UserName** in the **LogSignIn** action.

In this method I am calling LogSignIn action by sending HttpContextBase type object and notify enum to get the success or error message.

**Action Login**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(model);
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                SignInLogger.LogSignIn(HttpContext, Notify.Success);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
                SignInLogger.LogSignIn(HttpContext, Notify.Error);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
      }
}
```

In this method I am trying to log the user information to the DB but Idenity don't have the value in the Name.
**SignIn Logger**

```
public static void LogSignIn(HttpContextBase httpcontext, Notify notifymessage)
{
    using (var context = new WorkshopEntities())
    {
        MessageLog log = new MessageLog();
        log.Date = DateTime.Now;
        log.Type = (int)MessageLogType.Information;
        log.Message = "Logged In";
        log.CustomMessage = notifymessage.ToString();
        log.UserEmail = httpcontext.User.Identity.Name ?? "N/A";
        log.Address= HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        context.MessageLogs.Add(log);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So, far what I understand that **PasswordSignInAsync** task didn't complete and I am trying to fetch the information that is still not available.

I don't know it is a best approach or not but I am trying to log the user information at the time of user try to login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the user has successfully logged in, you could retrieve the **Username** from the model itself.

Other user information can be obtained as such:

```
var userName = model.Username;
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
string userid = user.UserId.ToString();
//Email
//Other properties...
```

Comment: HttpContext.User.Identity will be empty inside login action. You can find more details in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to retrieve user from HttpContext in the login action because it is filled from authentication cookie. Since login action is the one that sets this cookie. HttpContext.User will be filled with data only on subsequent requests. So the only way you can get the user name in the login action is from the model - which is totally fine if you do it on successful login:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(model);
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                SignInLogger.LogSignIn(model.Username, Notify.Success);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        ...
}

public static void LogSignIn(string userEmail, Notify notifymessage)
{
    using (var context = new WorkshopEntities())
    {
        MessageLog log = new MessageLog();
        log.Date = DateTime.Now;
        log.Type = (int)MessageLogType.Information;
        log.Message = "Logged In";
        log.CustomMessage = notifymessage.ToString();
        log.UserEmail = userEmail;
        log.Address= HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        context.MessageLogs.Add(log);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how can I achieve this using HttpContext right after the result is filled with  **PasswordSignInAsync** method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in a post-login bounce action if you want to perform something straight after login. It will ensure that the sign in completes and user data is available so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(model);
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                SignInLogger.LogSignIn(model.Username, Notify.Success);
                return RedirectToAction("LoginBounce", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
           }
        ...
}

[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginBounce(string returnUrl) {

     //TODO: get user details you need

     //do Log work
     using (var context = new WorkshopEntities())
     {
        MessageLog log = new MessageLog();
        ...

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: and how I will utilize **LoginBounce** method?

Comment: @ShahzadMirza I've outlined in my answer. on successful login, redirect to the new action (provided in my answer), do what you need to do then push to the original `returnUrl` you had